# Bash keyboard shortcuts in cmd.exe

Tags: windows-10, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, cmd.exe, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is it possible to get basic editing keyboard hotkeys for cmd.exe or any other windows terminal? Specifically I would like to use some or all of the following commands

```
Ctrl-A
Ctrl-E
Ctrl-F
Ctrl-B
Ctrl-P
Ctrl-N
Ctrl-K
Ctrl-Y
```

I've looked at some cmd.exe alternatives, but I haven't found this functionality  in any of them. If it can't be done natively, are there any work arounds or macros?

Comment: Just something to consider, most of these actually do stuff in most shells. For example, CTRL+A and CTRL+E jump to the beginning and end of the line in Bash in emacs mode.

Comment: All of these do things in normal bash shells. Is there a way to port this functionality to a windows terminal?